# Localization of ASP.NET MVC websites with GNU Gettext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, gettext

This might be an unusual question, but is there any framework or at least some helper classes that would help me use GNU Gettext for localizing a C# ASP.NET MVC website? I've been using Gettext in a previous (managed code) project and really appreciate the possibility to use PoEdit for translating the resources.

I guess this would mean coding a few HtmlHelper extension methods that can extract the resource strings from Gettext. There even seems to be some kind of C# gettext wrapper, but I wasn't able to find a manual or tutorial. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FairlyLocal is also nice. I modified it to my own needs and am pretty happy with what it offered:

http://www.fairtutor.com/fairlylocal/

Comment: There is also [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com) available for free (which I developed).

Comment: Excellent answers (both your answer and the comment)! I'll go with the Zeta Resource Editor since Resharper supports Regular resource files, but Fairlylocal looks great too.

Answer (score 5):

The Mono Project website has a [tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/I18nGettext) on how to use gettext in a C# application.

Answer (score 1):

Also this post covers the specific subject of this question, although it doesn't make clear how it obtains the catalog in managed-land: http://weblogs.manas.com.ar/spalladino/2009/10/01/using-gnu-gettext-for-i18n-in-c-and-asp-net/